# How to organize a recursive promises call

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, promise

I am working with the Facebook graph API, which often returns an 'unknown error' message, which I find if I retry the post a few seconds later it works without an issue.

This code will make a call to postAsync, upon receiving a success response it will resolve that with a new Promise, otherwise it will increment the attempts counter and call the function again.

```
function guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts){
  attempts = attempts || 0
  ++attempts
  return graph.postAsync(endpointId + '/feed', wallPost).then(function(response){
    return new Promise.resolve(response)
  }).catch(function(error){
    setTimeout(function(){    
      console.log(attempts)
      console.log(error)
      if(attempts == 2){
        return Promise.reject('Too many attempts')
      }
      else{
        return guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts)
      }
    }, 5000)

  });
}

guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, 0).then(function(value){
  console.log(value)
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error)
})
```

I want to be able to use the code as such, where I call guaranteedPost, and log to the console either the response, or the single 'Too many attempts' error message. However, at the moment I receive as my output:

```
undefined
Unhandled rejection Error: Too many attempts
```

Thus, the first call returns undefined and the second call, which has no error handling, blows up.

Also, I want to use this within the context of a larger function which can access variables defined earlier, thus I don't want to pull out the error and success handling into their own functions.

I can't help but feel that I'm very close, but this is after a complete refactor or two and I still can't quite nail it. How can I design this properly?

Comment: For recursion you have to call `guaranteedPost` from `guaranteedPost`

Comment: Sorry, I had just renamed the function for posting on S.O. The updated code actually reflects what I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your timeout logic out into an actual promise, and return that. By doing the `setTimeout` like that, you catch the error and return nothing, THEN queue up a new request with nothing to catch its failure. Promises are all about chaining.

```
function delay(ms){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts){
  attempts = attempts || 0
  ++attempts
  return graph.postAsync(endpointId + '/feed', wallPost).then(function(response){
    return new Promise.resolve(response)
  }).catch(function(error){

    // Return a promise that waits a little bit, then tries again.
    return delay(5000).then(function(){    
      console.log(attempts)
      console.log(error)
      if(attempts == 2){
        return Promise.reject('Too many attempts')
      }
      else{
        return guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts)
      }
    })

  });
}
```

I'd also simplify this code down a bit:

```
function delay(ms){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}


function guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts){
  return graph.postAsync(endpointId + '/feed', wallPost)
    .catch(function(error){
      if (attempts === 2) throw new Error('Too many attempts');

      // Return a promise that waits a little bit, then tries again.
      return delay(5000).then(function(){   
         return guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, (attempts | 0) + 1);
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to get it working. The missing piece for me was the capacity to pass 'resolve' into the Promise, which guarantees that only a single value will be returned. I read up on the MDN description of Promise.resolve but didn't find any info on it there. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I'm using Bluebird as a library. I'm pretty sure there is a delay method available, would it be a better idea to read up the docs on that and substitute that in place of setTimeout?

Comment: Yeah totally, just wasn't sure what library you were using so I went for the ES6 standard method.